# Migrate HyperV virtual images back to VirtualPC

Tags: hyper-v, virtual-machines, virtualization

Is it possible to migrate from existing HyperV virtual machines "back" to Virtual PC. 
And if so what is the procedure doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following steps would be a generic walk thru:

1. If you installed the Integration Components, just uninstall those and shutdown the VM
2. Migrate the VHD to the machine on which you will run VPC
3. Start Virtual PC and create your new VM that matches your host OS
4. Use VHD copied from step 2 for the virtual hard drive instead of creating new image
5. Power on your VPC and hope you don't need to re-activate if windows (hardware change)
6. Install VPC components
7. Use VM for whatever use you have intended.

Hope these steps help.

I would be interested to try and understand your need to move "back" from Hyper-V to VPC? I have found Hyper-V to be a more robust VM solution than VPC.

I am currently running 2k8 R2 RC and have not experience any issues with the host OS or the Hyper-V role.

Comment: I must move "back" as our corporate servers which are runnig VM for external customer access don't use HyperV. On our team however we use HyperV. So it's a BIG corporate thinking thing.

Answer (score 1):

Wayne said (usefully):

>
The following steps would be a generic walk thru:

1. If you installed the Integration Components, just uninstall those and shutdown the VM
2. Migrate the VHD to the machine on which you will run VPC
3. Start Virtual PC and create your new VM that matches your host OS
4. Use VHD copied from step 2 for the virtual hard drive instead of creating new image
5. Power on your VPC and hope you don't need to re-activate if windows (hardware change)
6. Install VPC components
7. Use VM for whatever use you have intended.

Hope these steps help.

I would be interested to try and understand your need to move "back" from Hyper-V to VPC? I have found Hyper-V to be a more robust VM solution than VPC.

I am currently running 2k8 R2 RC and have not experience any issues with the host OS or the Hyper-V role.

---

Let me add to that.  Hyper-V, since it supports multiple virtual processors and 64-bit OSes, exposes a virtual Advanced Programmable Interrupt Controller (APIC.)  Consequently, Windows uses an APIC HAL.  If you start a Windows image under VPC that's using an APIC HAL, you will see a failure to boot.  If you want to get Windows working, what you do depends on the Windows guest OS version.  Before you move the VHD, do the following.

With Windows Vista, Server 2008 or later, type:

bcdedit /set detecthal on

With earlier versions of Windows, go into Device Manager and "update driver" on the "computer" node.  Choose "Advanced Configuration and Power Interface PC."

Then shut the VM down and move the VHD.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual PC 2007 and Hyper-V share the same VHD format.  If you migrate the VHD files in question back to your VPC host and create VMs using them, you'll have your answer.